# My array produces NAN

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a program that takes in a variable number of one row matrices (also of variable length) and adds them together. So element one of array one adds to element one of array two and so on.

```
function add() {
var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
var z = x.split(" ");
var l = z[0].length;
var y = [];
y.length = l;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
for(j = 0; j<l;j++){
for(i = 0; i < z.length; i++){

y[j] += z[i][j];
 }
}
document.getElementById("output1").innerHTML = y;


}

 </script>
<input type="text" id = "input" value = "233,322,444"> 
<button onclick = "add();"> add </button>
<div id = "output1"></div>
```

this is a bit of the code I'm trying to get to work. array produces NAN,NAN..Until end of array. Any help would be much appreciated.

another common output for example is this undefined233,undefined322,undefined444. This was the result after I put in 233,322,444.

```
 Also all columns must be same length i.e z[0] is length of all sets of     numbers
```

Comment: Some sort of test input data might be useful to include on your question. Without knowing what's going into the arrays, its very difficult to make sense of the outputs you're taking about.

Comment: please add your input data to the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` will be a string of text. If you split this text at blanks, you'll get an array of substrings (z) with `z.length` elements.

I think your code wants input like `256 765 187 239` and should add 2,7,1,2 in y[0], 5,6,8,3 in y[1] and 6,5,7,9 in y[2];

These problems you'll get:

1. you assume, every group has the same length as group 0
2. before adding in y[j] you should do a y[j]=0;
3. z[i][j] is of type "string"

Comment: These are the inputs I do put in.Should parseInt(z[i][j]) work? though I thought there was no need for it because all inputs were numbers. Also all columns must be same length i.e z[0] is length of all sets of numbers